# Distributed System - How to guarantee at least once published a message?

Tags: microservices, publish-subscribe, distributed-transactions

How to maintain consistency between disparate system (aka bounded contexts) when failures happen before publishing the message in a service bus (it could be a queue ).?

I figured out 3 options:
1. Using Udi Dahan  approach ( Reliable Messaging - https://vimeo.com/111998645), i.e., maintain a published messages information in the same store as the entity that generated the event.
2. Process database transaction logging, and published it to a message bus.
3. Use event sourcing approach.

Is there any options besides that? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: This seems a bit too broad. What’s the actual problem you’re referring to? Which properties of “reliable messaging” do you require?

Answer (score 0):

Message brokers like RabbitMQ provide [at-least-once](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html) delivery guarantee.